# Android - Intent.Action_Send send multiple images without showing chooser dialog multiple times

Tags: android, image, action, send

In my App, I am creating a bitmap at run time and letting the user to share it. I am using ACTION_SEND to share the bitmaps (images). It works great but I have noticed that, few Apps like Whats App etc., reduces the image quality (if more than 100 KB) and the end user gets a blurry image. If I opt to choose Email client like Gmail then the image looks good at the receiving end. I am aware that WhatsApp compresses the picture so to overcome this issue I am thinking of sending multiple images instead of one big image.

What I want is,
If the APP has to sent three images, It should ask user only once to select the application that should be used to send the image and then within the code, I would identify which Application user has selected and then using the same application will send the remaining two images.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I luckily figured out my self

Here is the code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();                                      

shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
files.add(bmpUri1);  // uri of my bitmap image1
files.add(bmpUri2); // uri of my bitmap image2
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
```

Comment: Hi, Please share your code and also mention at which point this is not working.

Comment: I am using exactly the same code and it's working for all my installed apps (Gmail, Yahoo Mail, FB Messenger, Texting App), but not for the Facebook App. When FB Post Activity opens up, it does not show any images. If I just send 1 images, using ACTION_SEND and send Uri via shareIntent.putExtra, then the one image is displayed. Any insight into what the problem with FB might be? Thanks.

Comment: I have just tried to share on FB using the same code and it does work. Can you please check the FB version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send multiple images to a contact programmatically using below code.

```
            String smsNumber = "91809XXXXXXX";  //Remove + from number
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");
            sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUriArray);
            sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            sendIntent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


            try {
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Whatsapp have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Do let me know if you have issue